# Who has the head as of episode 2 of Durarara!!×2 Ten?

Tags: durarara

In the conversation between Seiji and ultra-stalker Mika at the end of episode 2 of Durarara!!×2 Ten, Mika claims that Namie probably doesn't know where the head is, and that Izaya probably doesn't have it either, since she wasn't able to find it when she snuck into Izaya's apartments.

In that case, who *does* have the head? I thought that Izaya *did*, in fact, have the head. Is it that Izaya has misled Mika somehow, or am I just misremembering something? And was Namie just lying when she said she'd give Mika the head? (I mean, Namie was obviously lying about being willing to give her the head, but did she even have the wherewithal to give Mika the head if she had wanted to?)

(I would appreciate it if stuff that the viewer isn't supposed to know at this point in the story were hidden in spoiler blocks.)